# Is ROP chain possible on 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, buffer-overflow

I recently started practicing binary exploitation on 64 bit linux. Problem is while chaining ROP gadgets we have to get their address on stack. But since 64 bit addresses are 6 bytes plus 2 null bytes. It's not possible to get null bytes on stack with strcpy like functions. Anyone able to do something about it yet ?

Comment: where do you get that "64 bit addresses are 6 bytes plus 2 null bytes"?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc each address in a 64 bit system is of 8 bytes. The first 2 bytes are null bytes and left 6 give the exact address. Example see this 0x7ffff7a3cdc0. It's 6 bytes. But when stored in registers it must be 8 bytes so they save as 0x00007ffff7a3cdc0.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc in chaining if i want to jump to 0x7fff7a3cdc0, I need to overwrite return address with 0x00007ffff7a3cdc0. If i don't it will consider the next 2 bytes.

Comment: wrong. There are a lot of 64-bit architectures and each have different address formats. Early x86_64 implementations have only 40 bits of significant in physical address but the use of canonical format makes it possible to extend to 48, 52 and up to 64 bits in the future. Many ARM64 implementations also use 33 or 40-bit address, but the top can be freely used for [tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer)

Comment: Oh well but my rop will only work if i fill next 8 bytes with address of rop gadget. And address is 6 bytes. I can't get 2 nulls on stack. I need to make rop chain. Can't input nulls in between.

Comment: [it's possible to do that](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3726/2563). Note that 32-bit addresses may well contains 0 bytes and it's still possible to exploit on those systems. 64-bit address may also contain all ones in the top bytes

Comment: 48 bits is the standard now for virtual address space. And 52 bit for physical. Currently no processor use complete 64 bits. Read this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#Limits_of_processors

Comment: of course I know. But did you read my comment above mentioning [canonical address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details)? Those are signed extended and the top bytes can be all 0s or 1s. And **even the middle bytes can be zero, too**. Anyway my point is that obviously ROP is possible on x86_64 and there are a lot of similar questions already https://security.stackexchange.com/q/180634/89181 https://security.stackexchange.com/q/117061/89181 https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3726/2563 https://security.stackexchange.com/q/143719/89181

Comment: Yeah. I read. Sry forgot u mentioned that.

Comment: I read most of them except msfencode on. I gotta try that. Thanks.

Comment: You can find some more info [here](https://blog.techorganic.com/2015/10/09/a-rop-primer-solution-64-bit-style/)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc that's not gonna work null bytes  aren't copied.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](https://teamultimate.in/return-to-libc/):
Return to libc chaining on 64 bit linux.
Strcpy will give problems because it won't copy null bytes. You ca use one gadget in that case.
It will still work the same with functions which copy null bytes.

https://teamultimate.in/return-to-libc/